# ¿Qué significa suds.client:http failed?

Tags: python, python-3.x, http, soap

Estoy trabajando con esto: Vi en algún lugar que era como se *debugueaba* un servicio web y me funciona el *debug* con este código:

```
from suds import WebFault
from suds.client import Client
import traceback as tb
import logging
from suds.sudsobject import Property

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)
logging.getLogger('suds.client').setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
logging.getLogger('suds.transport').setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

try:
    url = "http://services.prueba.net/SearchPersonService/SearchPersonWCFService.svc?wsdl"
    cliente = Client(url)
    cliente.set_options(location='http://services.prueba.net/SearchPersonService')
    print(cliente.service.SearchNationalPersonByIdentityNumber('91041940969'))
except WebFault as f:
    print(f)
    print(f.fault)
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
```

Esto me proporciona esta salida (*debug*):

```
"C:\Program Files\Python35\python.exe" D:/MenoresP27/index.py
DEBUG:suds.transport.http:opening (http://services.prueba.net/SearchPersonService/SearchPersonWCFService.svc?wsdl)
DEBUG:suds.transport.http:opening (http://services.prueba.net/SearchPersonService/SearchPersonWCFService.svc?xsd=xsd0)
DEBUG:suds.transport.http:opening (http://services.prueba.net/SearchPersonService/SearchPersonWCFService.svc?xsd=xsd1)
DEBUG:suds.transport.http:opening (http://services.prueba.net/SearchPersonService/SearchPersonWCFService.svc?xsd=xsd2)
DEBUG:suds.transport.http:opening (http://services.prueba.net/SearchPersonService/SearchPersonWCFService.svc?xsd=xsd3)
DEBUG:suds.transport.http:opening (http://services.prueba.net/SearchPersonService/SearchPersonWCFService.svc?xsd=xsd1)
DEBUG:suds.transport.http:opening (http://services.prueba.net/SearchPersonService/SearchPersonWCFService.svc?xsd=xsd4)
DEBUG:suds.transport.http:opening (http://services.prueba.net/SearchPersonService/SearchPersonWCFService.svc?xsd=xsd1)
DEBUG:suds.transport.http:opening (http://services.prueba.net/SearchPersonService/SearchPersonWCFService.svc?xsd=xsd5)
DEBUG:suds.transport.http:opening (http://services.prueba.net/SearchPersonService/SearchPersonWCFService.svc?xsd=xsd1)
DEBUG:suds.transport.http:opening (http://services.prueba.net/SearchPersonService/SearchPersonWCFService.svc?xsd=xsd1)
DEBUG:suds.transport.http:opening (http://services.prueba.net/SearchPersonService/SearchPersonWCFService.svc?xsd=xsd6)
DEBUG:suds.transport.http:opening (http://services.prueba.net/SearchPersonService/SearchPersonWCFService.svc?xsd=xsd1)
DEBUG:suds.transport.http:opening (http://services.prueba.net/SearchPersonService/SearchPersonWCFService.svc?xsd=xsd7)
DEBUG:suds.transport.http:opening (http://services.prueba.net/SearchPersonService/SearchPersonWCFService.svc?xsd=xsd1)
DEBUG:suds.transport.http:opening (http://services.prueba.net/SearchPersonService/SearchPersonWCFService.svc?xsd=xsd5)
DEBUG:suds.transport.http:opening (http://services.prueba.net/SearchPersonService/SearchPersonWCFService.svc?xsd=xsd1)
DEBUG:suds.transport.http:opening (http://services.prueba.net/SearchPersonService/SearchPersonWCFService.svc?xsd=xsd8)
DEBUG:suds.transport.http:opening (http://services.prueba.net/SearchPersonService/SearchPersonWCFService.svc?xsd=xsd1)
DEBUG:suds.transport.http:opening (http://services.prueba.net/SearchPersonService/SearchPersonWCFService.svc?xsd=xsd2)
DEBUG:suds.transport.http:opening (http://services.prueba.net/SearchPersonService/SearchPersonWCFService.svc?xsd=xsd3)
DEBUG:suds.transport.http:opening (http://services.prueba.net/SearchPersonService/SearchPersonWCFService.svc?xsd=xsd1)
DEBUG:suds.transport.http:opening (http://services.prueba.net/SearchPersonService/SearchPersonWCFService.svc?xsd=xsd4)
DEBUG:suds.transport.http:opening (http://services.prueba.net/SearchPersonService/SearchPersonWCFService.svc?xsd=xsd1)
DEBUG:suds.transport.http:opening (http://services.prueba.net/SearchPersonService/SearchPersonWCFService.svc?xsd=xsd5)
DEBUG:suds.transport.http:opening (http://services.prueba.net/SearchPersonService/SearchPersonWCFService.svc?xsd=xsd1)
DEBUG:suds.transport.http:opening (http://services.prueba.net/SearchPersonService/SearchPersonWCFService.svc?xsd=xsd1)
DEBUG:suds.transport.http:opening (http://services.prueba.net/SearchPersonService/SearchPersonWCFService.svc?xsd=xsd6)
DEBUG:suds.transport.http:opening (http://services.prueba.net/SearchPersonService/SearchPersonWCFService.svc?xsd=xsd1)
DEBUG:suds.transport.http:opening (http://services.prueba.net/SearchPersonService/SearchPersonWCFService.svc?xsd=xsd3)
DEBUG:suds.transport.http:opening (http://services.prueba.net/SearchPersonService/SearchPersonWCFService.svc?xsd=xsd1)
DEBUG:suds.transport.http:opening (http://services.prueba.net/SearchPersonService/SearchPersonWCFService.svc?xsd=xsd4)
DEBUG:suds.transport.http:opening (http://services.prueba.net/SearchPersonService/SearchPersonWCFService.svc?xsd=xsd1)
DEBUG:suds.transport.http:opening (http://services.prueba.net/SearchPersonService/SearchPersonWCFService.svc?xsd=xsd5)
DEBUG:suds.transport.http:opening (http://services.prueba.net/SearchPersonService/SearchPersonWCFService.svc?xsd=xsd1)
DEBUG:suds.transport.http:opening (http://services.prueba.net/SearchPersonService/SearchPersonWCFService.svc?xsd=xsd6)
DEBUG:suds.transport.http:opening (http://services.prueba.net/SearchPersonService/SearchPersonWCFService.svc?xsd=xsd1)
DEBUG:suds.transport.http:opening (http://services.prueba.net/SearchPersonService/SearchPersonWCFService.svc?xsd=xsd7)
DEBUG:suds.transport.http:opening (http://services.prueba.net/SearchPersonService/SearchPersonWCFService.svc?xsd=xsd1)
DEBUG:suds.transport.http:opening (http://services.prueba.net/SearchPersonService/SearchPersonWCFService.svc?xsd=xsd8)
DEBUG:suds.client:sending to (http://services.prueba.net/SearchPersonService)
message:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:ns0="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns1="http://CommonServices" xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <SOAP-ENV:Header/>
   <ns0:Body>
      <ns1:SearchNationalPersonByIdentityNumber>
         <ns1:identityNumber>91041940969</ns1:identityNumber>
      </ns1:SearchNationalPersonByIdentityNumber>
   </ns0:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
DEBUG:suds.client:headers = {'Content-Type': 'text/xml; charset=utf-8', 'SOAPAction': '"http://CommonServices/SearchPersonService/SearchNationalPersonByIdentityNumber"'}
DEBUG:suds.transport.http:sending:
URL:http://services.prueba.net/SearchPersonService
HEADERS: {'Soapaction': '"http://CommonServices/SearchPersonService/SearchNationalPersonByIdentityNumber"', 'Content-Type': 'text/xml; charset=utf-8', 'Content-type': 'text/xml; charset=utf-8', 'SOAPAction': '"http://CommonServices/SearchPersonService/SearchNationalPersonByIdentityNumber"'}
MESSAGE:
b'<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:ns0="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns1="http://CommonServices" xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><SOAP-ENV:Header/><ns0:Body><ns1:SearchNationalPersonByIdentityNumber><ns1:identityNumber>91041940969</ns1:identityNumber></ns1:SearchNationalPersonByIdentityNumber></ns0:Body></SOAP-ENV:Envelope>'
ERROR:suds.client:<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
(405, 'Method Not Allowed')
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:ns0="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns1="http://CommonServices" xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <SOAP-ENV:Header/>
   <ns0:Body>
      <ns1:SearchNationalPersonByIdentityNumber>
         <ns1:identityNumber>91041940969</ns1:identityNumber>
      </ns1:SearchNationalPersonByIdentityNumber>
   </ns0:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
DEBUG:suds.client:http failed:
b'<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">\r\n<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">\r\n<head>\r\n<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1"/>\r\n<title>405 - HTTP verb used to access this page is not allowed.</title>\r\n<style type="text/css">\r\n<!--\r\nbody{margin:0;font-size:.7em;font-family:Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;background:#EEEEEE;}\r\nfieldset{padding:0 15px 10px 15px;} \r\nh1{font-size:2.4em;margin:0;color:#FFF;}\r\nh2{font-size:1.7em;margin:0;color:#CC0000;} \r\nh3{font-size:1.2em;margin:10px 0 0 0;color:#000000;} \r\n#header{width:96%;margin:0 0 0 0;padding:6px 2% 6px 2%;font-family:"trebuchet MS", Verdana, sans-serif;color:#FFF;\r\nbackground-color:#555555;}\r\n#content{margin:0 0 0 2%;position:relative;}\r\n.content-container{background:#FFF;width:96%;margin-top:8px;padding:10px;position:relative;}\r\n-->\r\n</style>\r\n</head>\r\n<body>\r\n<div id="header"><h1>Server Error</h1></div>\r\n<div id="content">\r\n <div class="content-container"><fieldset>\r\n  <h2>405 - HTTP verb used to access this page is not allowed.</h2>\r\n  <h3>The page you are looking for cannot be displayed because an invalid method (HTTP verb) was used to attempt access.</h3>\r\n </fieldset></div>\r\n</div>\r\n</body>\r\n</html>\r\n'

Process finished with exit code 0
```

De aquí lo que veo es esto: **`DEBUG:suds.client:http failed:`**

Mis preguntas son:

- ¿Qué significa suds.client:http failed?
- ¿Por qué no logro consumir el servicio como es?
- ¿Qué significa `ERROR:suds.client:<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> (405, 'Method Not Allowed')`?

Comment: Te dice que el método con el cual estas haciendo la petición al servidor no está permitido, por lo que debes cambiar el método HTTP con el que haces la petición.

Comment: y cómo hago eso??? Wow, gracias por responder... Tienes algún ejemplo?? puedes compartirlo en la nube o enviarlo a aarzuagat@gmail.com Un abrazo y gracias por todo